# check if record exists then update else insert

Tags: sql-server-2014

i have to check if record exists in table , if there is record then update else insert.

```
Stg_table
Id  seq   name    company
1   1     aaa     yyy
1   2     aaa     bbb


table 
Id  seq   name    company
1   1     aaa     yyy
1   2     aaa     bbb
```

now I have another row in staging with sequence 3

```
Stg_table
Id  seq   name    company
1   1     aaa     yyy
1   2     aaa     bbb
1   3     aaa     www
```

I have to check if this exists in table, if it does not exist only then insert. I cannot use MERGE as it is giving me trigger issues and I tried using if exists(below is my code)

```
If exists(select 1 from stg_table s
 join table t
on s.id=t.id and t.seq=s.seq )
begin
update -----
end
else 
begin
insert -----
end
```

How ever, the records are going as updates because it is satisfying the condition. How do i insert in such cases?

```
table 
Id  seq   name    company
1   1     aaa     yyy
1   2     aaa     bbb
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create two separate statements. One that handles the updates and a second that handles the inserts.

Updates:

```
UPDATE t
SET ....
FROM table t
INNER JOIN stg_table s
    ON t.id = s.id
    AND t.seq = s.seq
```

Inserts:

```
INSERT INTO table (....)
SELECT ..
FROM stg_table s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM table t
    WHERE t.id = s.id
    AND t.seq = s.seq
)
```